# Datatables - remove 'x' in column filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, datatables

I am using datatables in a webpage PHP based. I want to remove the 'x' in column filters since it's not functional or if there is any way this comes functional. It is only functional to remove the string from the input box but doesn't remove the filter from the column.

For example, when I type a keyword it filters the table then if I click on the 'x' in the input box, it removes the keyword but the table stays filtered where the filter should be cleared.

check screenshot in the link below.
[image]

Comment: Some browsers style the search input type with a "clear" button or likewise. See the links above.  It has really nothing to do with DataTables or filtering, just a general behavior you can suppress using CSS.